# One field in posted array not binding to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have the following, abridged for clarity and confidentiality, viewmodels:

```
public class BoqReviewViewModel
{
    public List<BoqReviewItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<BoqReviewItemViewModel>();
}

public static BoqReviewItemViewModel FromEntity(GTT_BOQ_IMPORT import)
{
    var ret = new BoqReviewItemViewModel();

    ret.BOQ_IMPORT_ID = import.BOQ_IMPORT_ID;
    ret.ITEM_CODE = import.ITEM_CODE;
    ret.ITEM_DESC = import.ITEM_DESC;
    ret.UNIT = import.UNIT;
    ret.QTY = import.QTY;
    ret.RATE = import.RATE;
    ret.AMOUNT = import.AMOUNT;
    ret.ITEM_PAYS = import.ITEM_PAYS;
    ret.ITEM_CPA = import.ITEM_CPA;

    return ret;
}

public GTT_BOQ_IMPORT ToEntity()
{
    var ret = new GTT_BOQ_IMPORT();

    ret.BOQ_IMPORT_ID = this.BOQ_IMPORT_ID;
    ret.ITEM_CODE = this.ITEM_CODE;
    ret.ITEM_DESC = this.ITEM_DESC;
    ret.UNIT = this.UNIT;
    ret.QTY = this.QTY;
    ret.RATE = this.RATE;
    ret.AMOUNT = this.AMOUNT;
    ret.ITEM_PAYS = this.ITEM_PAYS;
    ret.ITEM_CPA = this.ITEM_CPA;

    return ret;
}

[Key]
public Guid BOQ_IMPORT_ID;
public string ITEM_CODE { get; set; }
public string ITEM_DESC { get; set; }
public string UNIT { get; set; }
public decimal? QTY { get; set; }
public decimal? RATE { get; set; }
public decimal? AMOUNT { get; set; }
public bool? ITEM_PAYS { get; set; }
public bool? ITEM_CPA { get; set; }

public bool IsFlagged { get; set; }
```

Then I have the following GET action for an index type view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BoqReview()
{
    var model = new BoqReviewViewModel();
    model.CONTRACT_ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    model.PROJECT_ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    model.Items = GetItems().ToList();
    
    return View(model);
}
```

Where `GetItems` is a method that returns an IEnumerable with three *fully populated* item level viewmodels. When I startup the app, I see a properly populated table with 3 rows with all columns properly populated.

This is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BoqReview", "Boq", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th class="col-header">
                Item Code
            </th>
            <th class="col-header">
                Item Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Unit
            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th>
                Rate
            </th>
            <th>
                Amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Item Pays
            </th>
            <th>
                Item CPA
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Items[i].BOQ_IMPORT_ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_CODE)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_CODE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_DESC)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_DESC)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].UNIT, new {style = "width: 120px;"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].UNIT)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].QTY)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].QTY)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].RATE)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].RATE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].AMOUNT)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].AMOUNT)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_PAYS, Model.YesNoSelectList)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_PAYS)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_CPA, Model.YesNoSelectList)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Items[i].ITEM_CPA)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].IsFlagged)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}
```

Everything looks perfect, yet when I submit the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BoqReview(BoqReviewViewModel model)
{
    using (var db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        foreach (var modelItem in model.Items)
        {
            var updated = modelItem.ToEntity();
            db.GttBoqImports.AddOrUpdate(updated);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("BoqReview");
}
```

The `BOQ_IMPORT_ID` field on each item viewmodel is an empty GUID, yet the displayed table shows a proper GUID. All other properties of the item level viewmodels are still populated.

What could be wrong that just this `BOQ_IMPORT_ID` is not properly model bound? When I debug the network call in Chrome tools, it shows a proper GUID value for each `BOQ_IMPORT_ID` in the form data posted:

```
Items[0].BOQ_IMPORT_ID: 610d9a12-920f-43aa-89bc-08b68067a462
Items[0].ITEM_CODE: AA1
Items[0].ITEM_DESC: Some A's and a 1
Items[0].UNIT: kg
Items[0].QTY: 200
...
```

### Update

Renaming the VM property in that class and in the view solved the whole problem. Maybe, despite several VS restarts, a machine restart mighty have somehow helped. This smells of temp files or some caching somewhere.

Comment: Try setting the BOQ_IMPORT_ID to a Html.HiddenFor(model.Items[i].BOQ_IMPORT_ID) field and see if this work.

Comment: @Dimitri I had it in a hidden field and it didn't work, so I made it a visible field to try and diagnose this better.

Comment: OK. Is BOQ_IMPORT_ID always defined as the same type (Guid in this case) and not 1 time Guid, the other a string for example, in your businesslogic/classmodel as well as your ViewModel? And also, is it NULL or 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 that you see for the Guid?

Comment: It's declared `Guid` all over, no conversions or anything funny, and I see `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, as it's non-nullable.

Comment: According to me you have to set a HiddenFor field so therefore you will need a property in your Model let's say selectedGuid which its value should point to the selectec row of your table. I tried this on my side and i can get the Guid value inside the property selectedGuid . Can you try this or if you have tried this, can you post the code please?

Comment: @Dimitri I have tried as a hidden again, e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].BOQ_IMPORT_ID)` before the first `<td>` in the table body, and it still comes back empty. I don't know what more code that what you've seen you still want to see though - there hardly isn't anything else.

Comment: Should your first line be @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Items[i].BOQ_IMPORT_ID)  instead of @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Items[i].BOQ_IMPORT_ID) (**m**odel becomes **M**odel)? Just trying to help here.

Comment: @Dimitri Thanks, that was a good spot on your part, but unfortunately it isn't the problem. I've even simplified the view to use a list of items as a model, so my key looks like `@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].BOQ_IMPORT_ID)`, but even that still has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for giving the solution that helped you! Seems indeed to be something cached somewhere ... Good luck with everything ;)